# Testing non-activity classes in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4

I know how to test Activity classes with JUnit 4 in Android but I am unable to understand how to test non-activity classes (which don't extends Activity, ListActivity, or some other Activity class, but uses some Android APIs). Please help me in this regard.

Comment: did you mean any broadcast reciever or services

Comment: @Vladimir Ivanov & @Android Developer: Yeah, I mean regular classes but they have references to Android specific classes like Envirnment, Bitmap, etc.

Comment: @dtmilano: I am just trying to use JUnit 4 but didn't succeed. See this for details: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2271

Comment: Why are you trying to use JUnit 4 when JUnit 3 is the supported version ?

Comment: @dtmilano: OK, I will go with JUnit 3.0 but I don't know how to test non-activity classes. I.e. I am interacting with SD card (for reading, writing, creating folders, etc.) and this logic is in a separate class (not an activity), so how could I test this class?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To test non activity classes:

1. create a test project
2. create a test case
3. run as Android JUnit Test

   ```
   public class MyClassTests extends TestCase {

   /**
    * @param name
    */
   public myClassTests(String name) {
       super(name);
   }

   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see junit.framework.TestCase#setUp()
    */
   protected void setUp() throws Exception {
       super.setUp();
               }

   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see junit.framework.TestCase#tearDown()
    */
   protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
       super.tearDown();
   }

   /**
    * Test something
    */
   public final void testSomething() {
               fail("Not implemented yet");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: what about if you need to use runTestOnUiThread method, if there is a thread to be tested?

Comment: I guess the only way you can test something that runs on the UI thread is with an Activity

Answer (score 4):

The Android SDK includes JUnit. In fact, the Android test classes such as AndroidTestCase and InstrumentationTestCase inherit from junit.framework.TestCase. This means that you can use a standard JUnit test case to test a non-Activity class and include it in Android Projects.

For example, you can create an Android Project with a simple class to test:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int getOne() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and an Android Test Project with a standard JUnit test to test this class:

```
public class TestMyClass extends TestCase {

  public void testMyClass() {
      assertEquals(1, MyClass.getOne());
  }
}
```

and run this on an Android device or on the Android emulator.

More information after seeing clarification of question in the comments:

AndroidTestCase or other Android test classes can be used to test non-Activity classes which need access to the rest of the Android framework (with a dummy activity provided in the setUp() if necessary). These give you access to a Context if you need to, for example, bind to a service.

Comment: You mean, for Activit classes I've to use Android JUnit and for non-Activity classes, JUnit?

Comment: I tried your approach and got this `#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (434C41535326494C453041525345520E4350500AB6), pid=3708, tid=2288
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0-b105 mixed mode)
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

`

Comment: @Greenhorn What was the exception from LogCat, if any? Do you have a basic example of what you are trying to test?

Comment: I didn't got any LogCat descriptions but a JVM crash report. See this post for details:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2271