# android test project does not find android-specific class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

in short: I have an android project (in Eclipse) and a test project for it. When I want to execute a test method (that uses android.location.Location) using JUnit, I get a classNotFoundException for android.location.Location.

Some more details: I have two Eclipse projects

- myApp
- myAppTest

The second one has been created using the Eclipse wizard for Android test projects and has a manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myApp.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.myApp" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have a class com.myApp.SomeClass in project myApp whose method someMethod(Location location) I want to test. Thus, I added the class com.myApp.test.SomeClassTest to the myAppTest project which looks as follows:

```
public class SomeClassTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        Location location = new Location("A");
        int result com.myApp.SomeClass.someMethod(location);
        //assert result here
    }
}
```

When I execute testSomeMethod as a JUnit test using the Android JUnit Test Launcher I get the exception:
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/location/Location
at com.myApp.test.SomeClassTest.testSomeMethod**

I have selected Android 4.2.2 as build target when creating the test project (i.e. the Android 4.2.2 libraries are included). (Also, I have included the JUnit 4 library.)

How can I avoid the exception? I don't want to start any Android emulator, I would just like to execute a plain JUnit test that tests methods which contain classes of the Android SDK (but not even any GUI classes).

Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Comment: Ah, by the way: I also get a NoClassFoundException when SomeClassTest extends android.test.AndroidTestCase and I run the test method as Android JUnit Test so that the emulator starts. The message is "Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Comment: In this line, android:targetPackage="myApp", you should use the whole package, like: android:targetPackage="com.example.myApp.test". See if it changes something.

Comment: If I run testSomeMethod in the orginal test class using the Eclipse JUnit Launcher, I get# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:129), pid=24028, tid=140249730012928
#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class

Comment: @ErickFilho: Thanks for the immediate comment ;-) "myApp" is actually the package (and the project name). I admit that's misleading, I will fix it. However, using package myApp.test as targetPackage does not change anything. What is the meaning of targetPackage, by the way ?

Comment: Take a look, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/instrumentation-element.html, just realized I added .test wrongly there.

Comment: I'm actually new to Android tests too, but this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830825/testing-non-activity-classes-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what is was trying (test a class that uses Android API without starting the emulator) is impossible. Instead, I changed SomeClassTest to extend AndroidTestCase and I am choosing "Runs As Android JUnit Test" which brings up the emulator. Then, everything works fine.